# Retrieve objects that don't have a relationship in ActiveRecord/Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I need to get all users who are not staff from my database:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :staff
  def is_staff?
    staff != nil
  end
end
class Staff < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :user_id
  belongs_to :user
end
```

So I could do this in code with:

```
User.all.select {|user| not user.is_staff? }
```

That seems to work, but I'd like to have this logic in the database and also I get an error in production with Heroku for some reason when trying to sort this way (dev with sqlite does not give me this error):

```
NAME_SORT = ->(a, b) {
  if a.first_name == b.first_name
    a.last_name <=> b.last_name
  else
    a.first_name <=> b.first_name
  end
}
User.all.select {|user| not user.is_staff? }.sort &NAME_SORT
```

The error I get for some reason is:

```
ArgumentError: comparison of User with User failed
```

Anyway, if I wanted to get all the users who are staff, that seems simple:

```
User.joins(:staff)
```

Is there an easy way to get users who are not staff? Maybe something like this?

```
User.not_joins(:staff)
```

And really I need the User to not be a Staff or Admin:

```
User.not_joins(:staff, :admin)
```

Comment: Use `User.includes(:staff).where(staff: {id: nil})` to get all the User without staff associated (you may have to rename the staff relation in the were clause to its pluralized version)

Comment: @MrYoshiji - interesting, so `includes` includes the users who aren't staff whereas `joins` does not. Thanks, you should put this as an answer

Comment: When you use includes and use what you include in the where, you do a LEFT JOIN whereas joins do a INNER JOIN.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To get all Users having no relation with Staff, you can use the following:

```
User.includes(:staff).where(staff: { id: nil })
```

It would work the same way for the the following query "Get all Staff having no user associated":

```
Staff.includes(:user).where(users: { id: nil })
                   ^            ^
```

**Something to know:** In the `includes` (and `preload` and `joins`) methods you have to use the relation's name as defined in the model (`belongs_to` & `has_one`: singularize, `has_many`: pluralize), **but** in the where clause you have to use the pluralized version of the relation (actually, the table's name).

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 solutions:

- do something not optimized and dirty like:

  ```
  User.where('id NOT IN(?)', Staff.select(:user_id).all.map(&:user_id).uniq).all
  ```

or like MrYoshiji said

```
    User.includes(:staff).where(:staff => {:id => nil})
```

- add a field to your table user, for know if your user have or not a staff, so you have to set this field to true after your create a staff for a user but you could get all users easily with

  ```
  User.where(:have_staff => false).all
  ```
- or you invert your relation and say Staff has_one User and User belongs_to Staff and for get all users you do

  ```
  User.where(:staff_id => nil).all
  ```

Comment: Thanks. I like @MrYoshiji's answer, the last 2 options are not possible in my situation